# SOAPUI - groovy script not working on ONE of machines

Tags: groovy, soapui, simpledateformat

see below simple groovy script for Date parsing:

```
def setProperty=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");
Date currentDate = new Date();
String tmpDate = currentDate

//setting current DateTime to corresponding property
def DateTime = new Date().parse("E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy", tmpDate).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
setProperty.setPropertyValue('DateTime', DateTime);
```

This scripts correctly works on some machines with Win 8.1, java 7 or 8 installed. But for one of machines (Win 8.1) it returns an error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jan 20 11:59:58 EET 2015"
```

What's the problem? Script absolutely the same...

Sincerely,
Dmitry

Comment: sorry, NOT, working, not NOW in title*

Comment: I edit your title, however you can edit your question at any time using `edit` link `:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is extremely awkward! You should consider using [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Formatter.html) to format your date straight up:

```
def propertiesStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
propertiesStep.setPropertyValue('DateTime',
    String.format("%tFT%tT", new Date(), new Date()))
```

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'll try that. I'm not dev, so my code, for sure, is awful.

Comment: @Dmitry I added an extra step to the script, above, for better coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems confusing... you're generating a `java.util.Date` with `new Date()`, then you're generating a `String` when you do `String tmpDate=currentDate`, then you're trying to get a `Date()` again parsing the `tmpDate` string and finally you're parsing the last date to get a string date with specific format...

I think that you must clean up your code a bit... I think that you're looking for something as follow:

```
def setProperty=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
def currentDate = new Date()
def dateTime = currentDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
log.info dateTime
setProperty.setPropertyValue('DateTime', dateTime)
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: thank u all for that help. Project correctly works on all machines, client is happy:)

Comment: @Dmitry it's nice to help you `:)`